# How to do "If [value] === [id]" in php

Tags: php, html

I want to make my code change an element if that element's id matches the value of the button.
as in:

if "button value" === "div id".
I'm rusty on PHP though and don't know how to do it. The html looks a bit weird because its a sql injection site, though I'm pretty sure that shouldn't mess with anything.

Relevant PHP:

```php
    <?php
    $ariabool="true";
        $gridclass ="gridhidden";
        if(isset($_POST['expand'])){
            if(isset($_POST['expand'])==='id'){ //first pass of this, it doesn't work but i don't know how to do it properly
                $gridclass = 'gridexpanded';
                $ariabool = 'false';
            }
        }
    ?>
```

Relevant HTML

```html
    <div class='kagrid' >
            <div class='griddisplay'>
                <img src={$row['img']} />
                <h2>{$row['name']}</h2>
                <div>{$row['primpro']}</div>
                <a href={$row['src']}>Image Source</a>
                <button type='button' class='expand' name='expand' value={$row['id']}></button> //button i want to compare the value of
            </div>
            <div id={$row['id']} class='$gridclass' aria-hidden='$ariabool'> //element i want to compare the id of
                <div class='gridcell bold'>Nicknames</div>
                <div class='gridcell'>{$row['nicknames']}</div>
                <div class='gridcell bold'>Pronouns</div>
                <div class='gridcell'>{$row['pronouns']}</div>
                <div class='gridcell bold'>Typical Age</div>
                <div class='gridcell'>{$row['age']}</div>
                <div class='gridcell bold'>Source(s)</div>
                <div class='gridcell'>{$row['source']}</div>
                <div class='gridcell bold'>Role(s)</div>
                <div class='gridcell'>{$row['role']}</div>
                <div class='gridcell bold'>Terms</div>
                <div class='gridcell'>{$row['terms']}</div>
                <div class='bold desc gridcell'>Description</div>
                <div class='desc gridcell'>{$row['description']}</div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: Did the answer work, if so, you should tick it.

Answer (score 0):

This is one way of doing it.

The coalescing operator **??** returns a blank string if the **POST** value is undefined.

```
<?php
  $ariabool=true;
  $gridclass ="gridhidden";
  $element = $_POST ['expand'] ?? '';
  if($element === 'id')
    {
      $gridclass = 'gridexpanded';
      $ariabool = false;
    }
?>
```